# Triple-boot Windows 7/Ubuntu 12.04/OpenSuse/ 12.2

Tags: dual-boot

I own a Toshiba Qosmio F60-11H, with features listed here http://www.toshiba.it/discontinued-products/qosmio-f60-11h/ to which I add that the card integrated DVB-T is produced by Yuan High Tech-although reported as Toshiba. I would like to install on the same computer Windows 7 HP 64bit by default, Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenSuse 12.2, with the help of Super Grub. I would like to have or know of a guide indication to proceed with this triple-boot system, keeping in mind that OpenSuse, rpm distro to my liking in KDE, has the characteristic of being a bit 'pushy and that, therefore, the ignition phase, when offers a choice of OS to boot, it appears as if it were present in several versions but even if it is always the same. Thanks

Comment: @EliahKagan Would this question: [What is the easiest and safest way to perform triple-boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182008/what-is-the-easiest-and-safest-way-to-perform-triple-boot) be better?

Comment: @karel Looks good. It might be good to have an answer that goes into more detail about boot loaders, but that can happen there. Close-voted.